# How can I rewrite this while to use a char array instead?

Tags: c

I am new to C so I am not able to figure out how to do this. I have a while loop like this:

```
char my_line[MAXLINE];
while(gets(my_line) != NULL) {
    //process line
}
```

Currently this while loop takes input from stdin. Can someone tell me how to use a char array instead i.e. read my data from a file into a char array and then pass the char array to the while loop?

Comment: Never, ever use `gets`.  Never.  Never, ever.  There is no way to specify the size of the buffer into which `gets` inserts data, so any program that uses `gets` has a critical security flaw.  `fgets` is a usable alternative.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: This is not my code but I will definitely keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy. Just use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/). This doesn't address dynamic memory allocation, this example uses a fixed sized char array.

```
   FILE * pFile;
   char mystring [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) 
   {
       perror ("Error opening file");
   }
   else 
   {
       fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile);
       fclose (pFile);
   }

   //mystring now contains the file with EOF terminator.
```

Comment: Awesome... Thank you so much!